# Group has correct permissions and user in group, but cannot access folder

Tags: permissions, raspbian, group

I'm trying to access a folder but I'm not allowed to.

The folder (`folderA`) permissions:

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwx--- 6 someuser groupA    4096 jul 24 21:26 folderA
```

The users in the group (`groupA`):

```
$ grep 'groupA' /etc/group
groupA:x:1003:pi
```

Trying to access `folderA`:

```
$ cd folderA
-bash: cd: folderA: Access denied
```

I am not allowed to access the folder as you can see, and for the record: I am user `pi` in this system.

Now when I do `sudo chmod -R 777 folderA` then I am allowed but I won't like this setting as I want to be allowed as group member and I do not want to allow others. What could be wrong in the setup?

Comment: The output for `grep 'groupA' /etc/group` doesn’t make sense (it doesn’t match `groupA`) — are you sure that’s the actual output?

Comment: completely right, i checked again and updated it should be correct now in my post. Sorry, it is groupA:x:1003:pi

Comment: What does `groups` output? Is this a newly-created group by any chance?

Comment: ah wow that is odd, it does not show groupA anywhere

Comment: can we have the output of `id pi` ?

Comment: UID=1000(pi) GID=33(www-data) groepen=33(www-data),1003(groupA)

Comment: missed question sorry, no it is not. system had couple of reboots with this group

Comment: Are the permissions of the parent directory of `folderA` correct?

Comment: thanks @MarkStewart, changing the parent's folder group did the trick althoug i find it somewhat strange that i was able to enter the parent folder and not folderA